# ios14 widget , "edit widget" disable ...way?

Tags: widget, ios14

I want to hide "Edit widget" when selecting long in ios 14 widget.

[image]

Comment: StaticConfiguration(kind: kind,
                            provider: Provider()) { entry in
            widgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }